# Auth0 JWT plugin and ionic2 - No Authorization header send

Tags: django, angular, ionic2, jwt

I have problem with integrating JWT token plugin from Auth0 with least Ionic2. I have absolutly no error but request is send without authorization header. My code:

app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { NoteService } from '../services/note.service';

let storage: Storage = new Storage();

export function getAuthHttp(http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    headerPrefix: 'JWT',
    noJwtError: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json'}],
    tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('id_token')),
  }), http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthHttp,
     {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: getAuthHttp,
      deps: [Http]
    },
    Storage,
    NoteService,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AppParameters } from '../parameters';
import { AuthFormModel } from '../models/authForm.model';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class NoteService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private note_url: string = AppParameters.ENDPOINT_URL + '/notes/';

    private notes: any;
    constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

    getUserNotes(){
        return this.authHttp.get(this.note_url);
    }

}
```

And component where I use service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NoteService } from '../../services/note.service';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  notes: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public noteService: NoteService
    ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.noteService.getUserNotes().subscribe(
            data => this.notes = data,
            err => console.log(err),
            () => {
              console.log('request complete');
              console.log(this.notes);
            }
        );
  }

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.25",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "noteman_js: An Ionic project"
}
```

Everything work, absolutly no error in console but header is still missing. Maybe i forget something? I try configuration from JWT plugin and lot of configurations from stack overflow.
Btw. Sorry for my terrible english :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one thing. In your service, you'll need to send the headers as options in your get request.

**For authHttp request**

*From reading the docs I believe the following would work*

[github: authO/angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#sending-per-request-headers)

In your service:
 NoteService class should look something like:

```
export class NoteService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private note_url: string = AppParameters.ENDPOINT_URL + '/notes/';

    private notes: any;
    constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

    getUserNotes(){
        return this.authHttp.get(this.note_url, {headers: this.headers});
    }
}
```

**For default angular Http request**

In your service:
You will need to import Request Options

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

And your NoteService class should look something like:

```
export class NoteService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    private note_url: string = AppParameters.ENDPOINT_URL + '/notes/';

    private notes: any;
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getUserNotes(){
        return this.http.get(this.note_url, this.options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesen't work. if I remove noJwtError: true, from AuthHttp then I get empty AuthHttpError and no request goes out at all. I think the problem is caused by storage.get('id_token') and i don't know hot to fix it.

Comment: ahh .. I didn't see that.

Comment: `storage.get('id_token')` returns a promise not a value. So you would have to use a .then((val)=>{ //val is the actual value you need })

Comment: Fixed, there is error in ionic documentation. In example where is storage.set they used this function synchronusly but is async function.

Comment: Can you please post the code how you got the value out of token because I am fighting this for last 5 days and I feel very stupid :)
This is my code:

    tokenGetter: (() =>getToken()),

export function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    storage.get('token').then((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      
      resolve(token)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(err)
      console.error("token errrrorrrr",err);
    });
  }) 
}

Answer (score 0):

Just use window.localStorage instead of ionic storage:

```
export function getAuthHttp(http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json'}],
    //tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('id_token').then((val)=>{return val}) ),
    tokenGetter: (() => JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("id_token"))),
    noJwtError: true,
    headerPrefix: "JWT",
  }), http);
}
```

As far as I can tell, the auth0 sdk is not using Ionic storage to store the id_token anyway... it's just using window.localStorage, so you might as well just use that too and its a synchronous method so avoids this promise stuff.